# External SVG file is NOT getting loaded using JQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to load simple svg file in HTML5 using JQuery. But i dont seem to get that effect in my page. Please help me solve this.

I have browsed and found the way, but it is not working for me. See my code below:

### SVG file: (Sample.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#svgfile').svg({loadURL: 'Sample.svg'});
}
```

MyHtml.html:

```
<div id="svgfile" style="background:#9b0141;width:400px; height: 400px;">
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No. I am using ie 9. Most of them have posted that they are successful using this piece of code. Dont know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$('#svgfile').svg({loadURL: 'Sample.svg'});` is not valid jQuery unless you are using some plugin you haven't mentioned.

try

`$('#svgfile').load('Sample.svg');`

Comment: it worked!!!.. Thanks a lot..So u mean, normal <svg> plugin content wont be loaded using $('#svgfile').svg({loadURL:....?

Comment: `svg()` isnt part of the jQuery library. You would have to include a plugin that extends jQueries functions to include an `svg()` function.

Comment: For anyone who may be interested: this http://keith-wood.name/svg.html is a popular jQuery plugin for loading "and manipulating" svg (inline or from files) and it has the syntax OP was trying `$('#svgfile').svg({loadURL: 'Sample.svg'});`. If you only need to load a svg file then you don't need the plugin, the example in this answer will suffice.

Comment: has anyone had a problem with modern <a href><rect ...></a> not working when using the jQuery .load(svg) method?

Comment: And if I want to load more than one svg file to a different element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery 3.7.1 and the code below...

```
<div id="svgfile"></div>
<script>
  $(function(){ $("#svgfile").load("test.svg"); });
</script>
```

... for my profile page on Gihub. Anyone can find the full code here:
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonSolutions.github.io/tree/master/sponsor/open_automotive